# firebase cloud function for sorting values

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to write a cloud function for firebase that can sort data by values, but it's not working. Here is my code

```
exports.membersposition = functions.database.ref('/queues/{queueid}/members').onWrite(event => {
const membersRef = event.data.ref;

return membersRef.orderByChild('timestamp').on('child_added')
    .then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot.key()));
});
```

Can any body fix this

Answer (score 0):

From the examples of Firebase query. try using it like

```
 return membersRef.orderByChild('timestamp').on('child_added',function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.key);
    });
```

instead of

```
return membersRef.orderByChild('timestamp').on('child_added')
    .then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot.key()));
});
```

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query